# Error Invalid Isolate Scope Definition en una directiva con AngularJS al reabrir modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-directivas, dropzone

tengo el siguiente problema.
Tengo una modal que hace uso de una directiva a la que se le pasan dos funciones callback y que, cuando abro la primera vez dicha modal, funciona perfectamente. El problema viene cuando cierro la modal y la vuelvo a abrir. En la consola me aparece el error:

```
Invalid Isolate Scope Definition
Invalid {3} for directive 'dropZone'. Definition: {... NaNd: '021' ...}
```

Aquí el código de la directiva:

```
moduloDirectivas.directive('dropZone',[
    function(){
        return config = {
            restrict: "A",
            scope: { 
                callbackUpload: '&callbackUpload', 
                callbackBeforeUpload: '&callbackBeforeUpload' 
            },
            template:'<label class="drop-zone">'+
                     '<input type="file" id="fileinput" />'+
                     '<div ng-transclude></div>'+       // <= transcluded stuff
                     '</label>',
            transclude: true,
            replace: true,
            require: '?ngModel',
            link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel){
                var upload = element[0].querySelector('input');    
                    upload.addEventListener('drop', uploadFileSelect, false);
                    upload.addEventListener('change', uploadFileSelect, false);

                    config.scope = scope;
            }
        }

        function uploadFileSelect(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            config.scope.callbackBeforeUpload({estado: true});
            var file = e.dataTransfer ? e.dataTransfer.files: e.target.files;
            file = file[0];

            var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = (function(file) {
                    return function(e) { 
                        var data = e.target.result;
                        var objParameters = {
                            data: data,
                            nombreFichero: file.name,
                            tamanio: file.size
                        };
                        config.scope.callbackUpload({data: objParameters});
                        angular.element("#fileinput").val(null);
                        config.scope.callbackBeforeUpload({estado: false});
                    }
                })(file);
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
]);
```

A ver si se os ocurre qué puede estar pasando.
Gracias.

Comment: ¿Alguna idea de qué puede estar pasando?

Answer (score 0):

De la documentación de AngularJS (las negritas son mías):

`& or &attr` - provides a way to execute an expression **in the context of the parent scope**. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name is assumed to be the same as the local name. 
Given `<my-component my-attr="count = count + value">` and the isolate scope definition `scope: { localFn:'&myAttr' }`, the isolate scope property `localFn` will point to a function wrapper for the `count = count + value` expression.

Apenas he trabajado con AngularJS, pero según entiendo debería existir en el contexto padre expresiones para las dos funciones que declaras:

```
scope: { 
            callbackUpload: '&callbackUpload', 
            callbackBeforeUpload: '&callbackBeforeUpload' 
        }
```

Revisa que cumples las condiciones requeridas

Comment: Si, están declaradas. Como comento, la primera vez que abro el modal, funciona perfectamente: llama a esas funciones sin problema. El problema es cuando cierro la modal y la abro de nuevo, da ese error. 
No se si ese error es porque tendría que volver a declarar la directiva o qué.